# Rails получение значения переменной

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть 2 класса: `Task` и `Project`. Связанные друг с другом отношением `has_many - belouse_to`.

Модели классов:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Как вывести значение `project.name` во view `task#index`?

Вытянуть id проекта которому принадлежит текущий `task` просто: `<%= task.project_id %>`, а вот вместо `id` вывести имя проекта не получается. Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Кхм... Вы [гайды](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark) вообще читали? .-.

Comment: @D-side читал, но не совсем понимаю к сожалению как из написанного можно найти ответ на решение своей задачи

Comment: А где у вас в контроллере заполняется `task`, раз вы его используете? И зачем вы используете в контроллере код, который находит значение и выкидывает вникуда?

Comment: Я откатил правку с добавлением нового вопроса после копирования/вставки кода из моего ответа. К этому вопросу она не имеет отношения.

Comment: У вас, видимо, проблема с осознанием того, что такое `<%= выражение %>` и что должен делать контроллер. Рекомендую пройти [Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/beginning).

Answer (score 1):

При условии, что вы смогли заполучить объект модели `Task` в переменную `task`, на что указывает:

> Вытянуть id проекта которому принадлежит текущий `task` просто: `<%= task.project_id %>`

В сущности название проекта возвращается следующим выражением:

```
Project.find(task.project_id).name
```

...`has_many` и `belongs_to` для такого не нужны. Но их активно используют. И не просто так.

**Такой код вы вряд ли встретите в реальных проектах**, потому что это разновидность кода, на большой процент состоящая из механического жонглирования названиями полей в базе данных, в Rails для этого завели некоторые конвенции и...

---

### [Ассоциации!](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark)

Первый аргумент ассоциации это название метода, который создаётся на этой модели. Что он возвращает?.. зависит от типа модели. Для `belongs_to` это сразу объект ассоциированной модели, поэтому можно сделать так:

```
task.project.name
```

Comment: `has_many` и `belongs_to` нужны в проекте для других целей. Добавил указанный вами код - но возникает ошибка `undefined local variable or methodtask' for #`

Comment: Мой прошлый ответ вам уже должен был намекнуть, что мой код для объяснения, а не для копирования. Он построен на вашем же якобы работающем примере: "Вытянуть `id` проекта которому принадлежит текущий `task` просто: `<%= task.project_id %>`"